# arm-none-eabi-ld - "cannot find gc-sections"

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker, arm, cross-compiling

I am setting up a CMake build for an excisting project, and has successfully compiled all sources (.c) and reached the linker-stage.

Here I run into the following error:

/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find gc-sections: No such file or directory.

The compilation is done using "arm-none-eabi-gcc" with the following flags:

```
-Wall  -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -std=gnu99 -mabi=aapcs -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard'
```

The linker uses the following flags:

```
-Wl,-Map=out.map -Wl,gc-sections -mabi=aapcs -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -T${LINKER_SCRIPT_PATH}
```

Anyone understand why the linker is loooking for `gc_sections`?

**Edit**: Apparently I miss the leading hyphens of the argument. The correct linker flag is of course `-Wl,--gc-sections`, not `-Wl,gc-sections`.

How embarrassing.

Comment: `Anyone understand why the linker is loooking for gc_sections?` - most likely, because of option `-Wl,gc-sections` passed to the linker. It should be `--gc-sections` or `-Wl,--gc-sections`.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I missed the leading hyphens of the argument. The correct linker flag is of course `-Wl,--gc-sections`, not `-Wl,gc-sections`.

How embarrassing.